# Rails 3: Injecting partials through conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm looking to inject a partial/offset of a views pattern based on conditional statements. Don't know how to do this or how complex it may be. To better explain, here's some pseudo examples:

Totals: 1 Post & 3 Jobs
Pattern: 1 Job - 1 Post - 1 Job - 1 Job

A post is inserted between 3 jobs because there is more than 2. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like this in your view file.

```
<% if @jobs.count > 2 %>
  <% render_post = true %>
<% else %>
  <% render_post = false %>
<% end %>

<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= job.some_attribute %>
  <% if render_post == true %>
    <%= render @post %>
    <% render_post = false %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When `render_post` is true, rails renders post. When it is false, rails doesn't render post. However, `render_post` value doesn't appear in the html file.

You need _post.html.erb in the Post's view file.